# Using a column field in SQL like or regexp operator

Tags: sql, sql-like, vertica, regexp-like

I have a query:

```
Select * 
from table 
where 
field1 LIKE '%12345%' (12345 being a column value : field2) *Works*
```

I want to use a column field value in the LIKE operator instead of hardcoding.
Tried using concat:

```
where field1 LIKE concat(concat('%',field2), '%') *doesnt work*
```

Tried using regexp_like:

```
where regexp_like(field1, Cast(field2 as character)) *doesnt work*
```

Comment: What is "field2"? A column name or what? How do you define "field2"?

Answer (score 0):

Use just one concat

```
where field1 LIKE concat( '%',TRIM(field2), '%')
```

Comment: I have tested the code before answer . have you error ? . if don't work could be dont match (but work) ..

Comment: I have update the answer with a trim for clean the field ... try

Comment: @Neha - just as an aside "doesn't work" *isn't* useful feedback to give people. Be *specific*. Is it returning no results, wrong results, an error message, etc? Those are all different ways in which a suggested answer may not work and knowing the specifics (e.g. if it's wrong results, how are they wrong/ If it's an error message, *what* is the error) can be immensely helpful in guiding people towards *helping* you, especially when they don't have access to your data nor know what your aim is (hint: adding sample data and expected results to the question would also help)

Answer (score 0):

See below:

```
dbadmin=> create table test1 (a varchar(100));

CREATE TABLE
dbadmin=> 

insert into test1 values('Good morining ');
 OUTPUT
--------
      1
(1 row)

dbadmin=> select * from test1 where a like '%'||a||'%';
       a
----------------
 Good morining
(1 row)
```